# Get URL from the onClick for scraping purposes

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

Have to automate the daily task of getting the particular URL out of the website. So thinking of creating a scraper to complete the work. But stuck at a point where **I want to get the url out of the onClick function which is inside of a div**

- This is the selector i am using to get the html of my target

```js
    const htmlString1 = $('div[id="download_link"] > a').html()
```

The result i am getting back is

```html
<div onclick="openInNewTab('https://example.com/');" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline" style="background-color:#18bc9c;color:white;">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i> ⚡Get The File⚡ <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
</div>
```

- All i want is, to Get the URL `https://example.com` from the above HTML

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of ugly but it works, you only have 2 single quotes so you can just split it and take the second element in the array.

```js
 const url = $('#download_link').html().split("'")[1];
 
 console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="download_link">
<div onclick="openInNewTab('https://example.com/');" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline" style="background-color:#18bc9c;color:white;">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i> ⚡Get The File⚡ <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to the following:

```
<div onclick="getURL('https://example.com/');" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline" style="background-color:#18bc9c;color:white;">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i> ⚡Get The File⚡ <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
</div>
```

and then your js looks like this:

```
function getURL(url)
  {
      console.log(url);
      //put your code here to do what you want with var url
  }
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/fraggley/pen/eYpMEzv

Comment: Actually i cannot change the html, because the site is not mine. I want to scrape the site for that result.